# Visual studio Firewall and SQL connection issues

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio-2010, database-connection, windows-firewall

I seem to have troubles to get my application (run from k) to connect to the database, this has occured after some changes i made to my `SQLExpress` instance and has probably something to do with the firewall.

The changes i made are as follows:

1. I used to connect to the database using the `sqlexpress` instance name, i changed this to be able to use localhost, i went to sql server configuration, enabled `TCP/IP` and put the correct port in there, `1433`. No problems here.
2. I also created a new Login and user for my database, given it datareader and datawriter options.

The problem is i can connect to the database using `localhost` on sql server management studie, this works fine.

I can also connect using an internal tool, also using the localhost.

There is 2 problems i am not able to fix:

1. The first problem lays in `Visual studio`, when i run my application
   there, i get unable to connect errors. I tried running without
   debugging and this solves the problem as windows asked me if i would
   allow my application to make changes blabla. Running with debugging
   doesnt ask me the same question but just throws me the error, hence
   i think this one is firewall related, when i disable my firewall
   completely it works.
2. Im getting cannot open connection database errors, this ofcourse when i run without debugging to avoid previous problem, somehow my
   application cant seem to find the database when i try connecting via
   localhost, as said before, i can connect via localhost using sql
   management studio.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks in advance!

Comment: Try running VS as an administrator.

Comment: Use wireshark and sniff your tcp/ip connection to see if this is a firewall issue. Just wondering, you connect to localhost using .\SQLEXPRESS ? then it connecto to localhost from local computer, so the NIC shouldn't access the firewall routing at all.

Comment: When i disable the firewall i dont get the connection error as stated above. Im not using ".\SQLEXPRESS" i use "localhost"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ive reinstalled the sqlserver this solved the issue. I can now work with localhost, though its not the solution i was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Try to run visual studio as administrator.

Right click on VS icon and choose **run as administrator.**

Or take a look at this question:
[Point to localhost\sqlexpress using only localhost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/449607/point-to-localhost-sqlexpress-using-only-localhost)

Comment: I run visual studio as administrator by default, i also tried the right mouse button just to be sure, but didnt fix it, thanks for thinking with me though :)

Comment: Already had sql configured to use localhost, it works when using microsoft sql server management studio, just not when using visual studio...

Comment: There are OleDB Connection and SQL Connection

Answer (score 0):

Try to switch off UAC. Helped for me